# How to update my php contact email form script to redirect to a url after submit?

Tags: php

I am using this email script (at the bottom). where and what should I include to redirect to a different url after submit? Also, is this script safe enough?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$my_email = "mymail@mail.com";

$from_email = "";

$continue = "/";

$errors = array();

// Remove $_COOKIE elements from $_REQUEST.

if(count($_COOKIE)){foreach(array_keys($_COOKIE) as $value){unset($_REQUEST[$value]);}}

// Validate email field.

if(isset($_REQUEST['email']) && !empty($_REQUEST['email']))
{

$_REQUEST['email'] = trim($_REQUEST['email']);

if(substr_count($_REQUEST['email'],"@") != 1 || stristr($_REQUEST['email']," ") || stristr($_REQUEST['email'],"\\") || stristr($_REQUEST['email'],":")){$errors[] = "Email address is invalid";}else{$exploded_email = explode("@",$_REQUEST['email']);if(empty($exploded_email[0]) || strlen($exploded_email[0]) > 64 || empty($exploded_email[1])){$errors[] = "Email address is invalid";}else{if(substr_count($exploded_email[1],".") == 0){$errors[] = "Email address is invalid";}else{$exploded_domain = explode(".",$exploded_email[1]);if(in_array("",$exploded_domain)){$errors[] = "Email address is invalid";}else{foreach($exploded_domain as $value){if(strlen($value) > 63 || !preg_match('/^[a-z0-9-]+$/i',$value)){$errors[] = "Email address is invalid"; break;}}}}}}

}

// Check referrer is from same site.

if(!(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))){$errors[] = "You must enable referrer logging to use the form";}

// Check for a blank form.

function recursive_array_check_blank($element_value)
{

global $set;

if(!is_array($element_value)){if(!empty($element_value)){$set = 1;}}
else
{

foreach($element_value as $value){if($set){break;} recursive_array_check_blank($value);}

}

}

recursive_array_check_blank($_REQUEST);

if(!$set){$errors[] = "You cannot send a blank form";}

unset($set);

// Display any errors and exit if errors exist.

if(count($errors)){foreach($errors as $value){print "$value<br>";} exit;}

if(!defined("PHP_EOL")){define("PHP_EOL", strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3) == "WIN") ? "\r\n" : "\n");}

// Build message.

function build_message($request_input){if(!isset($message_output)){$message_output ="";}if(!is_array($request_input)){$message_output = $request_input;}else{foreach($request_input as $key => $value){if(!empty($value)){if(!is_numeric($key)){$message_output .= str_replace("_"," ",ucfirst($key)).": ".build_message($value).PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;}else{$message_output .= build_message($value).", ";}}}}return rtrim($message_output,", ");}

$message = build_message($_REQUEST);

$message = $message . PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL."-- ".PHP_EOL."Thank you for using FormToEmail from http://FormToEmail.com";

$message = stripslashes($message);

$subject = "FormToEmail Comments";

$subject = stripslashes($subject);

if($from_email)
{

$headers = "From: " . $from_email;
$headers .= PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $_REQUEST['email'];

}
else
{

$from_name = "";

if(isset($_REQUEST['name']) && !empty($_REQUEST['name'])){$from_name = stripslashes($_REQUEST['name']);}

$headers = "From: {$from_name} <{$_REQUEST['email']}>";

}

mail($my_email,$subject,$message,$headers);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

after mail() add

```
header("Location: anotherlocation.php");
```

However to your second question, I'd use `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST`

Comment: genesis, also, any ideas why all gmail.com, hotmail.com mails work, but lets say if I write in the script something like myname@mysite.com (googleapps) I do not get the mail. If I send mail from gmail or hotmail site to myname@mysite.com it works fine.